# Why an array of structs containing a pointer member has to be const?

Tags: vala

This question actually arose when I was using the [`OptionEntry`](https://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/GLib.OptionEntry.html) struct which happens to have a `void*` field. So the example below is not too hypothetical.

```cs
struct Item {
    public string name;
    public void* data;
}

class Main: Object
{
    static int book_data;
    static int pen_data;
    
    const Item[] items = {
        { "book", ref book_data },
        { "pen",  ref pen_data }
    };
    
    public static void main(){
    }
}
```

This examples compiles OK. But when you make the `items` array a **non-const** variable:

```cs
   ...
    Item[] items = {
        { "book", ref book_data },
        { "pen",  ref pen_data }
    };
   ...
```

it fails to compile with the error: *Invalid type for member `data'*. And aside from that if you change the pointer member of the `Item` struct to a non-pointer member, the code compiles without error:

```cs
struct Item {
    public string name;
    public int data;
}
   ...
    Item[] items = {
        { "book", book_data },
        { "pen",  pen_data }
    };
```

Can somebody explain what's happening here. (I read the note about struct arrays on [Vala FAQ](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/FAQ#How_do_I_create_an_array_of_structs.3F).)